# Event Details from Database not display in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to display the results (e.g. the events) of my calendar from my database onto the FullCalendar, but for some reason, my PHP code won't pull those results in. I am initiating a try, catch in order to see if the process will go through upon connection is successful with database and yes I am connected successfully, however it is still not pulling those events. I am running a foreach and initiating them in an associative array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: './php/load.php',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "./php/insert.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end
                            },
                            success: function () {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                alert("Added Successfully");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },
                editable: true,
                eventResize: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "./php/update.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            id: id
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('Event Update');
                        }
                    })
                },

                eventDrop: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "./php/update.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            id: id
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert("Event Updated");
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function (event) {
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                        var id = event.id;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "./php/delete.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: id
                            },
                            success: function () {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                alert("Event Removed");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php

//load.php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

try {

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";

  $data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start_event"],
  'end'   => $row["end_event"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

} catch(PDOException $e) {

echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Comment: When you access `php/load.php` directly in your browser what do you get?

Comment: @SimonK it ouputs my results in an associate array, but I want those results to be outputted onto the FullCalendar.

Comment: Really? Shouldn't it be outputting a JSON string?

Comment: @SimonK sorry yes, it is outputting the associative array in a JSON string.

Comment: Can you try changing `events: './php/load.php'` to `eventSources: eventSources: ['./php/load.php']` and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: @SimonK it's still the same, not ouputting any of the results

Comment: Oh dear. Can you perhaps try adding a json header to your PHP file: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` - before you `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: @SimonK I was able to add the json header, however it's still not outputting the results onto the calendar. Just on the load.php.

Comment: Please give a sample of the JSON you're outputting from the PHP. Possibly something is wrong in the data, e.g. date is in the wrong format or something.

Comment: foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start_event"],
  'end'   => $row["end_event"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

@ADyson

Comment: That's your php code, which you've already shown. What I need to see is the _output_ of that code, specifically the output from the json_encode command